# Can hadoop-azure be configured to use active directory (tenant, appId, appSecret) auth for azure blob

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Hadoop-azure lib to read files from azure blob storage. From docs I have manual how to add Hadoop configuration to use Shared Access Signature (sas) or shared key authentication. Whereas it's possible to auth via Active Directory (tenant id/client id/client secret). And I found next way to configure it for Azure-Data-Lake-Storage-gen2, whereas I'm still curious can I somehow use it for azure blob (wasb/wasbs blobs)

```
hadoopConfig.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth");
hadoopConfig.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider");
hadoopConfig.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net", clientId);    
hadoopConfig.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net", clientSecret);
hadoopConfig.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storageName>.blob.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId
   +"/oauth2/token");
```

^
DOES NOT WORK FOR AZURE BLOB (exception still asking me for shared key)

There's `org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator` class inside Hadoop-azure, but I have no idea how to connect it to config.

My main code:

```
public void readFile(String blobURI) {
    InputFile file = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(blobURI), hadoopConfig);
reader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord> builder(file).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ABFS (azure blob file system)** in Hadoop  Supports reading and writing data stored in an Azure Blob Storage account and also supports the  configuration of multiple Azure Blob Storage accounts

All configuration for the ABFS driver is stored in the `core-site.xml` configuration file

To configuring Hadoop to access ADLS is to setup the Azure Data Lake File System. editing your core-site.xml, which contains cluster-wide configuration. The `core-site.xml` is located in `%HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop`
Need to set the configuration like

```
<configuration>  <property>
        <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
        <value>ClientCredential</value>
  </property>
  
  <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
      <value>YOUR TOKEN ENDPOINT</value>
  </property>  <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id</name>
      <value>YOUR CLIENT ID</value>
  </property>  <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.credential</name>
      <value>YOUR CLIENT SECRET</value>
  </property>  <property>
      <name>fs.adl.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem</value>
  </property>  <property>
      <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.adl.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.Adl</value>
  </property>  </configuration>
```

for more details refer this [document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-abfs-driver)  and [document2](https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4)